# Sylius EntityFilter choice from a part of resources

Tags: symfony, sylius

I used a `Sylius 1.0.0-beta1` and ported `EntityFilter` from `dev-master` due to lack of this functionality in last stable version. Everything works fine but is there any way of choosing not from all resources but only from part of them?
I need to make a filter based on Taxonomies. I have a few taxons which are city names and all of them have parent taxon called City (code: city). So I want to display in that filter all children of city taxon.

My grid configuration is shown below:

```
sylius_grid:
    grids:
        smartbyte_admin_products_by_event_archetype:
            ...
            filters:
                ...
                taxon:
                    type: app_entity
                    options:
                        fields: [taxon.id]
                        class: "%sylius.model.taxon.class%"
                city:
                    type: app_taxon
```

The first filter from configuration works and filters fine, except it takes all taxons, but I need to show only some.

I tried also make my own filter (the second one) but I get a text field instead of entity field in filter. Following the [docs](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/custom_filter.html) I created custom one. Here is my try:

```
<?php

namespace SyliusExtensionBundle\Form\Type\Filter;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

final class TaxonFilterType extends AbstractType {


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('city', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                          ->leftJoin('t.parent', 'taxon')
                          ->where("taxon.code = 'city'");
            },
            'label' => 'Miasto',
            'required' => false
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'sylius.ui.all',
            ])
            ->setDefined('fields')
            ->setAllowedTypes('fields', 'array')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'sylius_grid_filter_taxon';
    }
}
```

Service configuration:

```
services:
    sylius.grid_filter.entity:
        class: SyliusExtensionBundle\Grid\Filter\EntityFilter
        tags:
            - { name: sylius.grid_filter, type: app_entity, form-type: SyliusExtensionBundle\Form\Type\Filter\EntityFilterType }
            - { name: sylius.grid_filter, type: app_taxon, form-type: SyliusExtensionBundle\Form\Type\Filter\EntityFilterType }
    sylius.form.type.grid_filter.entity:
        class: SyliusExtensionBundle\Form\Type\Filter\EntityFilterType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: sylius_grid_filter_entity }
    app.form.type.grid_filter.taxon:
        class: SyliusExtensionBundle\Form\Type\Filter\TaxonFilterType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: sylius_grid_filter_taxon }
```

And lastly filter templates:

```
sylius_grid:
    templates:
        filter:
            app_entity: "SyliusExtensionBundle:Grid/Filter:entity.html.twig"
            app_taxon: "SyliusExtensionBundle:Grid/Filter:entity.html.twig"
```

Please guide my how can I restrict EntityFilter or how to make the custom filter work. I spent many hours on this subject and cannot see whereis the error.

Current effect below:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Current TaxonFilterType according to Paweł Jędrzejewski tips. Still doesn't work and dont detect fields option in configuration.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Krzysztof Wędrowicz krzysztof@wedrowicz.me
 * Date: 23.01.17
 * Time: 14:56
 */

namespace SyliusExtensionBundle\Form\Type\Filter;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

final class TaxonFilterType extends AbstractType {

    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'sylius.ui.all',
                'class' => 'Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                              ->leftJoin('t.parent', 'taxon')
                              ->where("taxon.code = 'city'")
                        ;
                },
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->setDefined('fields')
            ->setAllowedTypes('fields', 'array')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'sylius_grid_filter_city';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible via configuration. I will add it to the backlog, but not sure when it can be implemented. That being said, your custom filter is a good idea. You should do a small change and it should work: The form type should have `EntityType::class` in `getParent()` instead of using the `buildForm` method. And the custom query builder should be configured in `configureOptions` method, then it will render a proper field. Here is full code that should work:

```
<?php

namespace AcmeExtension\Form\Type\Filter;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

final class CityFilterType extends AbstractType 
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'sylius.ui.all',
                'class' => 'Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Taxon',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                        ->leftJoin('t.parent', 'taxon')
                        ->where("taxon.code = 'city'")
                    ;
                },
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->setDefined('fields')
            ->setAllowedTypes('fields', 'array')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'sylius_grid_filter_city';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but something is still broken. I get Twig error "The option "fields" does not exist" when I added options.fields as in entity filter. When I removed it, it still is a raw text input. I copied whole class from your solution.